# Dynatable data-dynatable-no-sort not working

Tags: dynatable

I added the data-dynatable-no-sort attribute to my table header like so:

```
<th data-dynatable-no-sort>Delete</th>
```

It doesn't work for me though.

I added the attribute to the delete column. Why isn't this attribute working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with data-dynatable-no-sort="true"